# Alternative to remote desktop, more a remote screen

Tags: 14.04, remote, administration

I'm using an Ubuntu pc for spotify, autoplay cd's, mediaserver with pictures synced by dropbox, that kind of stuff.

In general it should be an automated pc which wont be monitored too often. It is also placed in the living room and therefore it has no screen attached.

Now i'm using remote desktop which uses xfce. This is not optimal as the remote desktop connection makes a new desktop session which starts all kind of programs and processes that start to run for this "new" user.

What would be preferable is a remote window to the one and only session that is started when the pc boots.

Any suggestions how to realize this?

I'm happy to ditch the xfce solution, but I would really prefer a GUI environment.

It is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a vnc-server and vnc-client.

You could use tightvnc or realvnc.

I would prefer tightvnc (*sudo apt-get install tightvncserver*).

If the vnc-server starts at boot and autologin is configured it should work.

Comment: I tried this and it works! No double programs anymore. Thank you.